# Cookie not set with CORS Ajax request using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I've been struggling about this for a while. We're calling our internal service via Ajax which will set a cookie after the request is done. From what I've seen so far this can be done via `withCredentials` parameter. I've also check the example from Mozilla

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials

Which points me to this. http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/credentialedRequest.html

And it looks like it's working I just have to set the CORS correctly. However, when I copy the code and I tried calling my service I didn't see any cookie being set.

Here's the code.

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'MY SERVICE URL';
    var invocationHistoryText;


    function callOtherDomain(){
        if(invocation)
        {
            invocation.open('GET', url, true);
            invocation.withCredentials = "true";
            invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
            invocation.send(); 
        }
    }
    function handler(evtXHR)
    {
        if (invocation.readyState == 4)
        {
                if (invocation.status == 200)
                {
                    var response = invocation.responseText;
                    console.log(response);

                }
                else
                    alert("Invocation Errors Occured" + invocation.readyState);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("currently the application is at" + invocation.readyState);
        }
    }
```

This is the response I get

```
access-control-allow-credentials:true
access-control-allow-headers:Authorization, Content-Type, If-None-Match
access-control-allow-methods:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin:http://localhost:8888
access-control-expose-headers:WWW-Authenticate, Server-Authorization
access-control-max-age:86400
cache-control:max-age=600
Connection:keep-alive
content-encoding:gzip
Content-Length:56
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 07 Jul 2016 14:25:19 GMT
Expires:Thu, 07 Jul 2016 14:35:19 GMT
```

And this is the request header it makes

Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,th;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:name=Fe26.2**6cff63f4eb1d5d63c9ef3beb4618b19b4638f5a805030ac9e3e06f0f3561e6f1*gX0LowRnJ-Bc0YS5WAMFqQ*66rp6okC9kDZXmZ4rl8BVVlGOI_KcGlydCG-XnFmgUX4_e6CMeg6JCpjx12xEF5c**a454d2b7be5b7f32cc463aaf151f67fbeefedf4dbe0d389ba2fb19a1b6745ba3*XBh9bkxi6HLcB0zwm500nYjsiiUw7TRsCZB_p2xgln4
DNT:1
Host:MY INTERNAL SERVICE
Origin:http://localhost:8888
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8888/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
```

So, I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: There's a cookie visible in the request. What makes you think it isn't being set?

Comment: I checked with Chrome Developer tool and I didn't see that cookie. When I tried the example, I saw the cookie in Chrome Developer tool.

Comment: Also from the example, I see that in the response head there's a header set-cookie but when I changed to my internal service url and I didn't see any set-cookie in the response. So, I assume that the cookie is not set.